# Multi Classify into categories based on Email Subject and Body in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, multiclass-classification

My dataset as like below.

[image]

Subject column refers to Email SUbject and Problem description and Problem details column refers to Email body.

Based on both subject and emaail body keywords, i need to classify to which Queue it should belong to.

Previous queue column consists of 25+ different categories.

My dataframe shape is of (60697, 4).

Please advise on the approach i need to follow to classify. Which ML models i need to use to train the data and test the data.

I know a bit to use natural language tokenization concepts.

Classification is more like gmail inbox classification: Primary, Social and Promotions. However, here I have to categorize into 25+.

Comment: Can we consider `Previous Queue` as a known and correct label/class for the training data set?

Comment: yes. Previous queue needs to be considered as output for test data based on Email body and subject

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the following:

1. vectorize your subjects and email body using CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer, so you'll have your `X` matrix. You may want to test different `ngram_range`'s in order to improve the prediction performance
2. Factorize your classes, so you should have one integer for each class - this will be your `y` vector
3. split your `X` into `X_train` and `X_test` and `y` into `y_train` and `y_test`
4. train a LogisticRegression model using `X_test` and `y_test`
5. test it on `X_test` and `y_test`
   ...

Comment: Thank you Max for inputs! Let me try the approach as you said and hoping it works as I wanted it to. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Here's a recent blog article about multi-class classification similar to what @MaxU proposed https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f

Answer (score 0):

You could give FastText a try. Here is a link to [tutorial](http://%20%20https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html).

Fasttext uses the concept of [word embeddings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding) in the context of supervised classification. The key advantage of using fasttext is, it is very fast as it name says. It can handle 1000+ categories/labels easily.